# in-memory storing and working with large data lists Spring Boot 2 java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I have an application which does a lot of work with large in-memory data lists. Currently i use a singleton datacache structure as follows:

```
public class DataCache {

    private final Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<String>>> arraysMap = new HashMap();
    private final Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> integerMap = new HashMap();
    private final Map<String, Map<String, String>> stringMap = new HashMap();
    private final Map<String, Map<String, MyObject>> arraysMap = new HashMap();

    /**
     * Map for boolean locks used to temporaly disable
     * edition while the data changes.
     */
    private final Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> locksMap = new HashMap();

    private DataCache() {

    }

    private static final DataCache dataCache = new DataCache();

    public static DataCache getInstanceOf() {

        return dataCache;
    }

    ...getters/setters...
}
```

the `arraysMap` and `myObjectMap` are getting the majority of workload - something about 20-50/s list operations such as `put`/`replace`/`delete` and similar for the `myObjectMap` (sum for all objects). `maps` are accessed in multi-threaded context. Initially the this kind of load wasn't expected, but it seems to be working just fine. 
However, it seems like the the data complexity will grow as well as the load.

**Question** is - is it reasonable to switch to some external solution (`redis`?) or keeping this improvisation might be sufficient. The load might increase to max 500/s operations per map. Lists in `arraysMap` can be as big as 200mb.

Answer (score 1):

it is reasonable to switch to external cache solution such as redis/memcache, the most important benefit is you can scale-out your application easily when the work is becoming larger, you only need to deploy your application in other machines

[image]

Comment: yeah i understand that. in my case actually easiness of scaling is not very important factor. the questions is more about performance and the maximum load current solution or redis can sustain.